# How does replacing/overwriting data work in Bell-LaPadula?

Tags: bell-lapadula

We don't have write-down in Bell-LaPadula (star property) however does this apply only to appending or does it also apply to overwriting data?

Answer (score 1):

No write-down means you can't perform any action to make changes to a system below your authorization level. The purpose is to prevent higher authorized entities from intentionally or unintentionally leaving classified data in an inappropriate location. Applied properly, this should mean that appends, overwrites, new files, etc. cannot be written/created/appended/edited in any way.